# Поменять скрытый копирайт в дочерней теме вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Есть тема вордпресс Cookery Lite c дочерней темой. Я бы хотел изменить копирайт для этой темы так, чтобы при обновлении темы он не изменился. Но копирайт спрятан в папку inc и находится в файле template-functions.php. Простое копирование измененного файла в каталог дочерней темы ничего не приносит. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

В данной теме копирайты находятся в функции `cookery_lite_footer_bottom` в `inc/template-functions.php`. И что важно - есть проверка на существование этой функции.

Это значит, что можно скопировать эту функцию в дочернюю тему и изменить её содержимое как нужно.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста SeVlad а как это сделать?

Comment: Я скопировал функцию и вставил код в functions.php но выходят ошибки

Comment: Разобрался с ошибкой- не скопировал скобку. Код вставил и все заработало. Большое спасибо!